# Android OpenGL ES 1.0 generating a lot of Garbage Collection calls. (SpriteBatcher)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, garbage-collection

I have been working on moving a real-time Arcade type Android game from a Canvas-based rendering system to OpenGL. Because of my complete lack of experience with Android I chose to use [SpriteBatcher](https://github.com/twicecircled/Android-Sprite-Batcher), which is a Renderer and resource pipeline implementation. The process of moving over was fairly simple, but I ran into performance issues on devices using the Dalvik VM. As opposed to my ART device, where the GC is barely ever called and the game runs smoothly, the older Dalvik devices are making as many as five GC sweeps per second.

```
01-09 10:10:06.748: D/dalvikvm(5124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 530K, 49% free 3181K/6151K, external 1190K/1599K, paused 4ms+4ms
```

This is the type of message I am seeing constantly spammed whenever rendering is happening. There were some slight performance issues before the switch from Canvas which are now gone on the ART device, but the older devices are now laggier than with Canvas rendering. The game loop is being ran in the rendering thread, through the onDrawFrame() method of the Renderer. Setting a maximum framerate or changing rendering modes between ON_DIRTY and CONTINUOUSLY has not made any visible difference. I also tried removing all draw commands altogether and simply rendering a black screen, and the GC calls were still being spammed without any notable change.

As the latest development, I tried moving to sprite sheets, and performance improved extremely noticeably on a newer Dalvik device and also improved, though not enough, on an older Dalvik device. This is despite the GC messages still being spammed at the same rate. The above message is from this new version: the difference to the old ones is that the pause time has significantly decreased and the maximum heap size of the application has grown. The amount of memory freed has remained around the same level.

My question specifically is this: what is causing these constant GC calls, can it be fixed, and if it can't is this normal for a Java OpenGL application? With the SpriteSheets performance seems visually decent on any even slightly newer device, I'm just concerned that the GC calls are a sign of some crucial mistake on my part or in the code of the Renderer.

Comment: The garbage is being collected because the garbage is being generated. You should figure out what's being allocated and if it's possible to avoid those allocations. The DDMS "allocation tracker" provides information on recent allocations (https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/allocation-tracker/index.html). See also Android Breakout (https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout) for an example of a simple GLES2 game that does no allocations in the game loop.

Comment: I just took a look at the codebase for SpriteBatcher and umm yeah I'm not sure wouldn't have picked it as it looks like usage of Iterators and type conversion within what I think is the batchDraw call. Either of those would be creating objects and a big no-no in any performant game. As you say you are not experienced in Android it may help to watch two old Google IO videos on Real-Time games. While some parts are dated the programing related stuff is still useful: https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic and https://youtu.be/7-62tRHLcHk

Comment: Thanks for the comments, they confirmed what I suppose I already suspected. I will be working on a Renderer of my own based on these principles, and I'll take another close look at my game loop as well.